# How to create endpoint in Jersey for POST requests with or without body

Tags: java, post, jersey, server, jax-rs

I have an API created with Jersey

There's currently an endpoint to which users can make POST requests. There is no body required, as all the information is in the url.

```
@POST
@Path("entries")
@Produces(MEDIATYPE_JSON_AND_XML)
public Response createEntry(){
    ...
}
```

A new, *empty*, entry is created and the id is returned.
Content-Type of the request doesn't matter, as there is no request body data.

Now it should also be possible to set specific fields of the new entry during the request, using FormData. For this request a body is necessary, and the `Content-Type` must be `multipart/form-data`.

So I've created a second function:

```
@POST
@Path("entries")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data");
@Produces(MEDIATYPE_JSON_AND_XML)
public Response createEntryWithParam(@FormDataParam('param') String param){
    ...
}
```

This second function works te send the parameter in the request. But by adding it, the first stops working.

Sending a request without `Content-Type` will throw a `NullPointerException`. Probably because the `@Consumes` triggers some kind of `Content-Type`-check, which fails.

Is there a way to have one endpoint accepting POST requests with or without request-body?

*edit* So, I would like to receive all multipart/form-data requests in the seconds function, and use the first as a kind of catch-all for other POST requests to that endpoint

Answer (score 4):

Currently I have a work-around in place. 
If a POST request comes in without MediaType (Content-Type) or request-body, I automatically add an empty JSON object and set the Content-Type accordingly.

```
@Provider
public class ContentTypeRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext crc) throws IOException {

        if (crc.getMethod().equals("POST") && crc.getMediaType() == null && crc.getLength() == -1){
            crc.getHeaders().add("content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream("{}");
            crc.setEntityStream(in);
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but is kinda *hacky* in my opinion. I'm interested to know if there are better ways to achieve my desired result.